# I need to make a program that accepts numbers 0-9, and A-z upper and lower case. How do you make the code throw an error if the input isn't right

Tags: python

```
#accepts input of 10 (or more) letters or numbers, 
#Only letters or numbers can be accepted, if the input is not a letter or a number then the program will not accept the input and ask the user to try again.
#only 1 letter or number can be input at a time (so you will need 10 or more input requests)
#Any letter or number can be input in any order
#After each input is accepted, the program will display that input and all the other inputs in sequential order of numbers 0-9 first, Capital letters A-Z second, lower case letters a-z third.
#Has header information and comments defining the purpose for each section of code.
#
#This represents how the receiving computer will accept packets in any order and have to organize the packets to be in sequential order.

print("When imputting data only 1 number between numbers 0-9, capatal letters A-Z, and lower case letters a-z.")

input_1 = input("input data #1: ")

input_2 = input("input data #2: ")

input_3 = input("input data #3: ")

input_4 = input("input data #4: ")

input_5 = input("input data #5: ")

input_6 = input("input data #6: ")

input_7 = input("input data #7: ")

input_8 = input("input data #8: ")

input_9 = input("input data #9: ")

input_10 = input("input data #10: ")

inputs = (input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4, input_5, input_6, input_7, input_8, input_9, input_10)

if inputs > 9:
    print("error")
else: 
   print(sorted(inputs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with all the valid inputs then make it check if the user input is present in that list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
# String containing all valid values
VALID_INPUTS = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
inputs = []


# Checks if input data in VALID_INPUTS. If not, get new input data
def validate(value):
    if value.upper() in VALID_INPUTS and len(value) == 1:
        inputs.append(value)
        return value
    return validate(input("invalid input; try again: "))


def main():
    print("When inputting data only 1 number between numbers 0-9, capital letters A-Z, and lower case letters a-z.")
    for i in range(10):
        value = input(f"input data #{i + 1}: ")
        print(validate(value))
    if len(inputs) < 10:
        print("error")
    else:
        print(sorted(inputs))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From your criteria I assumed you want to check if the list contains 10 inputs, so I used:
if len(inputs) < 10:
print("error")
instead of:
if inputs > 9:
print("error")
which wouldn't work in the first place since you do not use len(). The validate function converts the input to its capital form if it is a string and checks if it is valid. If the value is in the VALID_INPUT string and its length is 1, the value is printed and appended to inputs, if not a new input is requested. Hope this is what you wanted.